# Time Series Plot in R, dealing with missing data

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart

I am trying to create a Time Series Plot of my data - that is exploring DyadPairs (two countries) over time in how they employ various kinds of attacks (cyber attacks vs. Militarized Interstate Disputes).

Here is what a section of my data looks like:

```
   Dyadpair   year   cyberattack  cyberseverity  MID   MIDhostility  
   200345     1992   NA           NA             1     3.00
   200345     1993   NA           NA             2     2.667
   200345     1998   NA           NA             12    2.667
   200345     1999   NA           NA             16    2.500
   20045      2000   NA           NA             0     1.00
   2365       2000   NA           NA             3     1.75
   2365       2008   6            3.833          NA    NA
   2356       2009   2            2.50           NA    NA
   2365       2014   7            3.14           NA    NA
```

I would like to create a Time Series plot that shows: 
1) How a Dyadpair changes over time in how they employ cyber attacks and how the severity of those cyber attacks changes over time
2) How a Dyadpair changes over time in how they employ MIDS (militarized interstate disputes), and how the hostility of those MIDS changes over time.

The problem is that I have a lot of missing data (NAs). This is because the cyber data only runs from 2000-2015, while my other dataset runs from 1992-2010.

How should I go about creating the Times Series plots I described above despite this problem of missing data?

---

Update: I figured out how to use “filter” feature of dplyr to select one Dyad:

```
library(dplyr)
USRUS <-total %>%
select (Dyadpair, year, cyberattack, cyberseverity, MID, midhostility) %>%
filter(Dyadpair == "2365")
```

And I was able to create a plot using this code:

```
## Scatterplot to reflect change over time for the United States
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(USRUS, aes(x = year, y = cyberattack, color = cyberseverity)) + 
geom_point(alpha=0.6) +
xlab("Year of Cyber Attack") + ylab("Number of Cyber Attacks") +
labs( size = "Severity of Cyber Attack" ) + 
labs(subtitle="USA and Russia over the years in cyberspace",
title="The Evolution of Rival Attacks") + theme_bw()
```

But how do I go about creating a plot that shows BOTH cyber attacks (and severity) and military attacks (and severity) over time for this particular dyad (2365: USA and Russia)? Because so far, my plot is only reflecting the behavior of USA and Russia in Cyberspace - it does not include anything about MIDS or MID hostility/severity.

Comment: What did you try? `plot` function nicely ignores NaN, so there should be no reason you can't plot them. If you show what you tried and the error you got, we might help

Comment: @Chelmy88, `NaN` is not the same as `NA` ... but the rest of your comment still applies.

Comment: @r2evans Indeed...

Comment: newtoR, while the topic of [*imputation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)) is relevant to data-missingness, I feel it does not apply here, so you are left with either showing only years where you have data in both, or accepting that one value will begin well into the plot. Your data is a good start, thank you for including it, and it might help to have data where we actually see the same `Dyadpair` (perhaps 2-3) across this time-span. As Chelmy88 suggested, it should still plot just fine, but that depends on how you are doing that. Can you include some code?

Answer (score 0):

You have two challenges: *visualization* and *data wrangling*. Missing data is actually not one of your challenges, as you'll see once your data is in order. When you're new to R, figuring out a plan of attack can be its own challenge, but it should start with the end goal in mind. In this case I would suggest making two plots:

- One showing the number of attacks over time, and
- the other showing the severity of attacks over time.

**Data Wrangling**

You should start by getting your data tidy. That means each type of variable (e.g. year, severity of attack, etc...) gets one (and only one) column, and each observation gets one row. Right now some of your variables are spread across multiple columns. For example, unless I'm misinterpreting your data, MIDhostility and cyberseverity really refer to the same thing, a measure of the severity of an attack.

It will help to consider the structure of your data. You really have observations of 5 variables.

- Dyadpair
- year
- attack category (MID or cyber)
- number of attacks in the category
- severity of attacks

The following code creates a dataframe with the data you shared, tidies it, then plots it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

original.df <- tribble(
~Dyadpair, ~year, ~cyberattack, ~cyberseverity, ~MID, ~MIDhostility,
200345,     1992,   NA,           NA,             1,     3.00,
200345,     1993,   NA,           NA,             2,     2.667,
200345,     1998,   NA,           NA,             12,    2.667,
200345,     1999,   NA,           NA,             16,    2.500,
20045,      2000,   NA,           NA,             0,     1.00,
2365,       2000,   NA,           NA,             3,     1.75,
2365,       2008,   6,            3.833,          NA,    NA,
2356,       2009,   2,            2.50,           NA,    NA,
2365,       2014,   7,            3.14,           NA,    NA
)

# Split the data into separate data frames for military and cyber. Rename
# columns for severity and attack number for consistency with the other dataset

military.df <- select(original.df, Dyadpair, year, attack = MID, severity = MIDhostility) %>%
  filter(!is.na(attack)) %>% # remove rows with no data
  mutate(attack_type = "MID") # add column identifying attack type

cyber.df <- select(original.df, Dyadpair, year, attack = cyberattack, severity = cyberseverity) %>%
  filter(!is.na(attack)) %>%
  mutate(attack_type = "cyber")

# Now combine the two dataframes into one. We've already ensured
# that they have the same columns, so we'll just concatenate them.
# Since attack_type is a categorical variable, we should make it 
# a factor.

df <- bind_rows(military.df, cyber.df) %>%
  mutate(attack_type = factor(attack_type))

df

# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Dyadpair  year attack severity attack_type
# <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>      
# 1   200345  1992      1     3    MID        
# 2   200345  1993      2     2.67 MID        
# 3   200345  1998     12     2.67 MID        
# 4   200345  1999     16     2.5  MID        
# 5    20045  2000      0     1    MID        
# 6     2365  2000      3     1.75 MID        
# 7     2365  2008      6     3.83 cyber      
# 8     2356  2009      2     2.5  cyber      
# 9     2365  2014      7     3.14 cyber
```

**Visualization**

Now plotting. We'll create separate lines for the two attack types, identifiable by color. You can experiment with things like using points and smooths instead of lines; tinkering with the plot is part of working out how best to visualize the data.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = attack, color = attack_type)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = severity, color = attack_type)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

You also asked about plotting data for a single Dyadpair and said that you would like year, number of attacks, and severity of attacks shown for both military and cyber categories. There are only so many aesthetics to which you can map data and you're starting to run out but here goes.

- x-axis year
- y-axis number of attacks
- color severity of attacks

Because you said the time scale is likely to be very different for cyber and military, we can create side-by-side plots that share the y-axis but are free to vary in the range of their x-axes.

```
usrus.df <- filter(df, Dyadpair == "2365")

ggplot(data = usrus.df, aes(x = year, y = attack, color = severity)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(attack_type)) +
  ylab("attacks") +
  ggtitle("USRUS")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and advice - especially your tip on starting with the end goal in mind. 

The data wrangling makes a lot of sense. I have done that for all of my data - but now I have three follow-up questions.

1. Is it fine that I have combined “severity” into one category/plot - even though the scales for those attack severities are not necessarily the same ? (They come from two different datasets. MID hostility is on a scale from 1-5, and the cyber hostility is on a scale from 1-10).

Comment: 2. Organizing my data into a frame that includes an “attack type” category now means I have 1016 observations. (Prior to my data wrangling, I only had 992 observations). Because the cyber data is so small, it doesn’t really show up on my ggplot during the years 2000-2010. Is there something I can do about that?

Comment: 3. These plots also don’t really give me any information about dyads. I am assuming that I won’t be able to get all of the Dyadpairs onto one plot, as there are so many. What if, to get around this, I picked a few specific dyadpairs to give my readers a “case study” example of what this might look like over time? Would it be possible for me to pick a dyad (e.g. 200645 - which represents the UK and Iraq) and create a plot for that specific dyad -- to give my readers a little bit more information about which attacks (cyber or MID) a dyad uses over time?

Comment: 1) If the scales for severity are different, then I would not put them in the same plot; 2) Create separate plots for military and cyber attacks. The plots will scale to the data; 3) You'll have to play with this. You can use `dplyr::filter` to get rows for specific Dyadpairs. You could try plotting lots of them at once by mapping color to Dyadpair to see whether large-scale trends show up.

Comment: One quick follow-up about plotting. Please see my updated post.

Comment: @newtoR I added code to produce your additional plot.